# Combining fancyBox Scripts

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm new to fancyBox and having trouble combining some of the commands - I was hoping someone here could help me out.  I'd like to combine the following three scripts but so far I've had no luck.  I'm at a loss and would appreciate any help.

## 1:http://jsfiddle.net/ZePx5/

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
helpers : {
    title: {
        type: 'outside'
    }
}
```

});

## 2:http://jsfiddle.net/nJfAZ/

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    padding : 0
});
```

## 3:http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    }
});
```

I would like fancyBox to work with all 3 conditions at once, but I just keep breaking fancyBox when I try to combine them.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Hi the solution should be:

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'outside'
        }
    },
    padding : 0,
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    }
});
```